# How can I detect what is causing a div to scroll

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a complicated page with lots of JQuery Dialogs and other widgets. (thus no jfiddle sorry) Some of the dialogs have divs that allow scrolling. (overflow-y with a fixed height) If I click on one dialog, the divs within another dialog will scroll back to the top. This is annoying to the users.

How do I determine what is adjusting the scroll on that DIV? (Create a breakpoint, or some intercept to log a stack trace or something). I fear it is happening is some external library.

My initial approach was removing things until it stopped happening, I removed what I could but because of the complicated nature of the system I was unable.

My next approach was to build the system up until it started happening. Unfortunately I cannot replicate it.

If I do a $("#abc").scroll(function(){console.log("Scrolling")}); I do not see anything when the scroll happens automatically (though I do see it if I scroll manually)

What is left is catching it in the act. What can I do to catch it in the act and fix my issue?

Here is a fiddle that shows the problem. It seems to be related to this version of JQuery UI(1.10.3) with jquery 1.10.2 because using the default fiddle jquery stuff would not replicate it
http://jsfiddle.net/F8qGb/3/

This code isnt really relivant but I am not sure what is, and its required for the jsfiddle link

```
$(function()
{               
    $( "#w1" ).dialog();
    $( "#w2" ).dialog();
});
```

Edit:

Turns out this is a bug in jqueryui

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9725

Comment: Add some code. Can't help you without seeing the problem

Comment: try checking it out in the browsers developer tools section

Comment: I cant add the code because it is too large. I am actively trying to replicate the issue on jsfiddle but cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome debugger (F12), you can pause on events by going to **Sources -> Event Listener Breakpoints**. Expand the **Event Listener Breakpoints** item, then expand the **Control** item and check the box for `scroll`.

Comment: Seems this break point is for scrolling the browser not the div itself

Comment: This is a useful tool in my arsenal though Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this help, The issue seems to happen, during the blur event. within jquery and that helped me narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

While logging the events, this is your friend

```
console.log(this);
```

This will add the current object to the console. You can see it there, which element is making the event occur. And you will be able to handle the event, since you're having alot of code, it would be hard for you to judge too!

Comment: How do I get the event? If I do a $("#abc").scroll(function(){console.log("Scrolling")}); I do not see anything when the scroll happens

Comment: You will not see, untill you go to the Console! Console is in the Inspector..Press F12 and then go to console..if you;re using Chrome then it is the second button from bottom left side! :)